# Как удалить фотографии из Google Photos

Tags: google-plus

Ситуация следующая.
iphone, приложение загрузило over 3000 фото.
Сам сервис отличный. Однако мне захотелось загрузить фото в оригинальном качестве и далее удалить их с телефона (сейчас они загружены в "безлимитном режиме" - ужаты).

Если я иду в приложение iOS - оно удаляет фото и из телефона. если иду в веб-версию, тоже самое. Происходит синхронизация и фото удаляются отовсюду.

Единственный вариант разумный - выкачать все с айфона - удалить везде все и пересинхронизировать.

Но я не верю, что в Google не предусмотрели кнопку "удалить не удаляя с синхронизированных устройств".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, эти две ссылки будут полезными:
[Удаление фотографий и видео](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1304803?hl=ru) - описано, как это сделать из приложения для iOS.
[Как включить/отключить автозагрузку? Как удалить/сохранить фото?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-ru/wE7K5p-kuS4)